# Is there a way for combining all the terms in a set in python?

Tags: python

I made this code that is supposed to print random letters, and I want it to show a real word, and I can only make it print a set.I have no idea how to do so.I tried using try in a while loop but it shows me "syntax error".Also, How can I remove the if == then part so I don't have to type this like crazy?
Code:

```
import random
import time
random_list = []
num = 0
while 1+1==2:
   time.sleep(1) 
   alpha = random.randint(0,26)
   beta = " "
   if alpha == 0:
      beta = ' '
   if alpha == 1:
      beta = 'a'
   if alpha == 2:
      beta = 'b'
   if alpha == 3:
      beta = 'c'
   if alpha == 4:
      beta = 'd'
   if alpha == 5:
      beta = 'e'
   if alpha == 6:
      beta = 'f'
   if alpha == 7:
      beta = 'g'
   if alpha == 8:
      beta = 'h'
   if alpha == 9:
      beta = 'i'
   if alpha == 10:
      beta = 'j'
   if alpha == 11:
      beta = 'k'
   if alpha == 12:
      beta = 'l'
   if alpha == 13:
      beta = 'm'
   if alpha == 14:
      beta = 'n'
   if alpha == 15:
      beta = 'o'
   if alpha == 16:
      beta = 'p'
   if alpha == 17:
      beta = 'q'
   if alpha == 18:
      beta = 'r'
   if alpha == 19:
      beta = 's'
   if alpha == 20:
      beta = 't'
   if alpha == 21:
      beta = 'u'
   if alpha == 22:
      beta = 'v'
   if alpha == 23:
      beta = 'w'
   if alpha == 24:
      beta = 'x'
   if alpha == 25:
      beta = 'y'
   if alpha == 26:
      beta = 'z'
   random_list.append(beta)
   print(random_list)
   time.sleep(1)
   num = 0
```

Comment: How would your code know its a real word? you can look store this as a string and just access each letter using its index. For example `letters = "ABCDE"` I can do `print(letters[2])` which will print C. So it will essentially index it by number for you.

Comment: It won't .this was to randomly generate crazy letters.No word checker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"".join(random_list)`. This puts `""` between all terms of `random_list` and joins them as string. For how to optimize if part, you can use ASCII representation of characters. Lowercase letters are in range 97-122 and for `" "`-space we will use 123 and check that:

```
import random
import time
random_list = []
num = 0
while True:  # using True instead of 1+1==2 is better
    time.sleep(1) 
    alpha = random.randint(97,123)
    if alpha == 123: 
        beta = ' '
    else:
        beta = chr(alpha)  # converting integer to character
   random_list.append(beta)
   random_word = "".join(random_list)
   print(random_word)
   time.sleep(1)
   num = 0
```

If you have other purposes for `random_list`, you don't need this part. If you don't need list for some particular purposes, you can use string:

```
import random
import time
random_word = ''
num = 0
while True:  # 
    time.sleep(1) 
    alpha = random.randint(97,123)
    if alpha == 123: 
        random_word += ' '
    else:
        random_word += chr(alpha)  # converting integer to character
   print(random_word)
   time.sleep(1)
   num = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import string
import random

def random_word(length):
    lookup = ' ' + string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join([lookup[random.randint(0,26)] for i in range(length)])

random_word(4)
```